# PYTHON - Zip each file in directory independently

Tags: python, zip

I've been looking through and have tried a few different codes without results. What I'm trying to do is zip each file in a subdirectory/folder independently.

Ex:

> FileName.prj
>
> FileName.dwg
>
> FileName.mp3

Each as it's own .zip

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please update those in the question.

Comment: post the codes that you've tried.

Comment: format the question using these guidelines
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import os
import zipfile

folder = "/tmp/in"
dest_folder = "/tmp/out"
l = [os.path.join(folder, fname) for fname in os.listdir(folder)]
os.chdir(folder)

for f in l:
    f_name = f[f.rfind("/")+1:]+".zip"
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(f_name, 'w')
    z.write(f_name[:f_name.rfind(".zip")])
    os.rename(folder+"/"+f_name, dest_folder+"/"+f_name)
```

where folder is you folder that contains files you want to zip and dest_folder is folder where the zip files will be written.